# .bz2 pipe extract with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, stream, gzip, tar, bzip2

I want to extract **.tar.bz2** like the following with tar.gz with node.js:

```
request.get("localhost/file.tar.gz")
.pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
.pipe(tar.Extract({path: "./test"}))
.on("error", function(err){
    console.log("Error on extract", err);
})
.on("end", function(){
    console.log("done.");
});
```

The part "zlib.createGunzip()" should be replaced by a bz2-deflator. Does anyone know a working package for this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked [npm](https://npmjs.org/) yet?

Comment: I checked https://npmjs.org/ but i haven't find any workable.

Comment: I personally always use @shockpkg/archive-files for that

Answer (score 3):

Use https://github.com/regular/unbzip2-stream.

Then https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-fs.

Not my repo.

Example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const bz2 = require('unbzip2-stream');
const tarfs = require('tar-fs');

fs.createReadStream('foo.tar.bz2').pipe(bz2()).pipe(tarfs.extract('data'));
```

Above example will extract `foo.bar.bz2` into `data/` directory.

Comment: If anyone is unzipping it as a different file type, instead of `.pipe(tarfs.extract('data'))`, use `.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('data/filename.extension'))`

Answer (score 0):

They discuss the same issue here also: https://github.com/cscott/seek-bzip/issues/1